# Default values for bit fields in c++11

Tags: c++11, bit-fields

This works:

```
struct A {
  unsigned int x = 0;
};
```

This also works:

```
struct A {
  unsigned int x : 1;
};
```

Is it possible to combine the two? I.e., initialize and specify size simultaneously? Or do I need to explicitly write a constructor to do this?

Comment: Thanks, TonyK. Sounds like c++14 should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a quick look at the grammar of [class.mem]:

> *member-declarator*:
>       *declarator virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> pure-specifier<sub>opt</sub>*
>       *declarator brace-or-equal-initializer<sub>opt</sub>*
>       *identifier<sub>opt</sub> attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>* : *constant-expression*

Bit fields are the third option, members with initializer are the second. So you cannot have both.

However, you *can* initialize named bit fields in constructor initializer lists, just like any other non-static data member. (But you cannot initialize *unnamed* bit fields, since they are not members.)